# Selenium ChromeDriver sometimes doesn't log in with cookie injection

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape data off a password-protected Wordpress page; the data I'm interested in is populated via javascript, so I need those scripts to run.

I wrote some code to get a logged-in browser driver by injecting cookies gotten with a `requests` session:

```
class LoggedInBrowser:
    @staticmethod
    def get_browser_with_cookies(cookies=None):
        browser = Chrome(options=Options())
        browser.get(url_404)  # must preload site
        for cookie in cookies:
            browser.add_cookie({"name": cookie.name, "value": cookie.value})
        return browser

    @staticmethod
    def get_logged_in_cookies():
        with requests.session() as session:
            r = session.get(url_login)
            soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")
            nonce = soup.find(id="woocommerce-login-nonce")["value"]
            payload ={
                "username": email,
                "password": password,
                "woocommerce-login-nonce": nonce,
                "_wp_http_referer": "/account/",
                "login": "Log+in"
            }
            r = session.post(url_login, data=payload)
            return session.cookies
```

and some code to get what I'm interested in

```
        with LoggedInBrowser() as browser:
            browser.get(url)
            try:
                WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
                    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_attribute(
                        (By.XPATH, "//a[@data-file and @aria-label='Play']"),
                        attribute_="data-file",
                        text_="https"
                    )
                )
            except Exception as e:
                content = browser.page_source
                soup = bs(content, "lxml")
                body = soup.select("body.logged-in")
                ic(body)
```

(`ic` is a logging library)

Unfortunately this code shows that sometimes (seemingly random) the page does not get logged in, so no matter the timeout the data will not get populated; I tried arranging it into a `while` loop wrapping the `with` block (i.e. forcing a re-instantiation of the driver), and that sometimes works immediately, and sometimes after dozens of tries.

Why could that be happening, and/or how could I debug this?

Thanks